# Which pattern has been found?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

In the following wrong code, I would like to have the following infos for each match found.

1. The alternative `\w+` or `\d+` that has been found.
2. The position in the text of the match found.

I would like to use this with more than two basic alternatives. Is it possible without using brute-force ?

### WRONG CODE

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+)|(\d+)")

text = "a word or 2, or three"

for x in pattern.findall(text):
    print(x)
```

### OUTPUT

```
('a', '')
('word', '')
('or', '')
('2', '')
('or', '')
('three', '')
```

### OUTPUT EXPECTED

```
('a', 0, '(\w+)')
('word', 2, '(\w+)')
('or', 7, '(\w+)')
('2', 10, '(\d+)')
('or', 13, '(\w+)')
('three', 16, '(\w+)')
```

Comment: That's a good question. How to know which of the two groups in the OR was matched. I'll be watching this thread =)

Comment: Are you wanting to return the match and the match position together?

Comment: Yes plus also the winning pattern if it is possible.

Comment: My output looks different than yours: http://pastebin.com/neXrC2dZ

Comment: @projetmbc `plus also the winning pattern if it is possible` lolwut ? You could use named groups for the first question.

Comment: @rdodev I've the corrected this.

Comment: @projetmbc Do you mean something like this? [See here..](https://eval.in/74553)

Comment: @hwnd That's does the job for the point 2. Sorry I'm a very beginner with regexes. Thanks !

Comment: @HamZa Do you have a little example ?

Comment: For point 1. What exactly are you wanting to do?

Comment: @projetmbc [Something like this](http://regex101.com/r/sN2hB1) `(?P<word>[^\W\d_]+)|(?P<digits>\d+)`.

Comment: I'v updated my question. Maybe a better solution seems to name the alternative patterns and to have their name, rather that the pattern, as it has been suggested by HamZa.

Comment: it hasn't been explicitly mentioned, so I'm gonna say it, `\w` will match numbers, you have to use `[^\W\d_]` as Hamza just did, or `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: @HamZa With your help, I can find the name of the match by using `print((m.group(), m.start(), [x for x in ['word', 'digits'] if m.group(x) != None][0]))`. Is there a more elegant way ?

Comment: @projetmbc well then, if you solved it you might write an answer. [It's totally fine !](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments, I have the following solution.

### CODE

```
import re

text = "a word or 2, or three"

print('---')

pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<word>[^\W\d_]+)|(?P<digits>\d+)")

for m in pattern.finditer(text):
    name = next(k for k, v in m.groupdict().items() if v)
    print((m.group(), m.start(), name))

print('---')

pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<one_word>[^\W\d_]+)|(?P<some_digits>\d+)")

for m in pattern.finditer(text):
    name = next(k for k, v in m.groupdict().items() if v)
    print((m.group(), m.start(), name))
```

### OUTPUT

```
---
('a', 0, 'word')
('word', 2, 'word')
('or', 7, 'word')
('2', 10, 'digits')
('or', 13, 'word')
('three', 16, 'word')
---
('a', 0, 'one_word')
('word', 2, 'one_word')
('or', 7, 'one_word')
('2', 10, 'some_digits')
('or', 13, 'one_word')
('three', 16, 'one_word')
```

Comment: `name = next(k for k, v in m.groupdict().items() if v)`

Comment: Good idea because there is no need to give the list `['word', 'digits']`. I update the answer with your trick. Thanks a lot ! :-)